# IOS Background and Network

Tags: ios, background-process

We have a backgrounded app which lets the user make network requests to do things like post location to social media (Twitter/Facebook) when buttons are pressed on a paired bluetooth device.

We are seeing issues where the app has no network connectivity for a brief moment when it has been sitting idle (5+ minutes) and then the share button is pressed and we try to send the network request. On subsequent presses it is fine.

My guess is that the OS is putting the network to sleep and our app is trying to do something before it has had a chance to come back. I am not sure how to investigate but hoping I would ask the question here first to see if someone can point me to any docs to prove my theory.

Comment: What bluetooth version/protocol is the paired device using? Is it LE by chance?

Comment: It is not the LE (Lower Energy) version . I believe the version is 3.x